# where to find library dependencies for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I'm new to Android development and am currently looking at a library on github where the user can drag and swipe items.  The project is using an outside library from:

import co.paulburke.android.itemtouchhelperdemo.helper.OnStartDragListener;

I know that in Eclipse I could just import the jar file and this import would work, however in android studio I usually update the dependencies within the gradle file however i do not know where this library is located.  Is there an alternate way of using this library, or some way to find it? The link is the project I am currently working with

https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528104/difference-between-library-library-project-external-libraries/33532055#33532055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you're looking for is contained in the project itself:

https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/helper

When libraries have (outside) dependencies, they do declare them themselves in their own `gradle.build` file (transitive dependencies) and you don't have to take care about that.

Library artifacts declared in `build.gradle` files are usually stored at [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) or [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter).