# Adding gradle dependency to library aar package

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I am making a library project for a vendor and it needs Android Volley as a dependency. I have used this [Create aar file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio) to create the .aar file and to include this in a test project I am using this [Adding local .aar files to Gradle build using "flatDirs" is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working). The library is linked fine and there are no errors in the project compilation. But at runtime the test application crashes saying it cannot find Volley

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/in.gridsync.acttest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

My Gradle file for the library project is like this

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

and in the test project the gradle is this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.gridsync.acttest"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':openapp-library')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

I assumed, when the .aar package was created, it'd use and include the dependency it has on Volley library. Can someone please throw some light on this?

Comment: mate why not just add Volley from the depeneices tab on Project Structaure?

Comment: add testCompile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

Comment: @ItzikSamara, I dont want my vendor to add anything except for the aar package. That makes sense right? Because if I use some other library in the future, I dont want him to change his application code no more than just replacing the new **.aar** package which I give

Comment: How did you solve this, I face the same problem!

Comment: did you solve this ?

Comment: @NoamSegev As of now I couldn't find any official supported solution. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700581/android-studio-how-to-package-single-aar-from-multiple-library-projects), it seems there is no official support yet

Comment: @ChakradharReddyVeeramreddy any updates on this ? facing the same with retrofit

Comment: @user2450263 couldn't find any solution to this... Had to instruct our clients to include all the necessary libraries

Comment: @ChakradharReddyVeeramreddy thank you for the response, might need to do the same. Haven't been able to find an alternate solution...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Opened a new question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593149 - have a look, please, if you found a solution.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: anybody solved this issue, facing the exact same issue with volley

Answer (score 1):

Far as I know, you must add "@aar" for the .aar libraries. Also the jar file isn't required, it downloads that by itself.
Try this:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19@aar'
```

Comment: I tried his just now, this isn't working. The **.aar** doesn't still include the volley library in itself.

Answer (score -1):

One alternative solution is to place the dependent libraries as static jar file(s) in the "libs" folder of your project, instead of using gradle dependency. When generating aar file, the jar files under libs folder will be included in the aar.